# How to limit user input to a predetermined number of integers

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using scanf (with a loop) to assign integers into an array. I want the user to only input 8 integers ( it will be on one line), into the terminal. If they enter 9 numbers I want the program to print an error message.

I've tried to combine an if statement with scanf.

```
int main(){
int input[8] = {0};
int countM = 0;

while(countM < 9){
    if(scanf("%d", &input[countM]) < 8){
        countM++;
    } else{
        printf("Invalid input");
        exit(0);
    }
}
return(0);
}
```

It doesn't detect the 9th input. I want it to output "Invalid Input".

Comment: If you only want to read 8 integers, don't attempt to read a 9th one into `input[countM]` since it will result in undefined behavior (attempt to access `input[8]`). Try reading an integer first, then only if successful, put it into the array and increment your count. As @xing points out, check the manual page for `scanf`. The return value indicates how many values were read or EOF. The comparison with 8 makes no sense here.

Answer (score 3):

You say the input will be all on one line. So input one line to a string and check it out. This tries to scan for a 9th input.

```
int input[8] = { 0 };
char dummy[8];
char buff[200];
if(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin) == NULL) {
    exit(1);                // or other action
}
int res = sscanf(buff, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%7s", &input[0], /* etc */, &input[7], dummy);
if(res != 8) {
    exit(1);                // incorrect inputs
}
```

Here is a fully working example, improved from @AnttiHaapala comment and cut down to accept two numbers instead of 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int input[2] = { 0 };
    char dummy;
    char buff[200];
    if(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin) == NULL) {
        exit(1);                // or other action
    }
    int res = sscanf(buff, "%d%d %c", &input[0], &input[1], &dummy);
    if(res != 2) {
        exit(1);                // incorrect inputs
    }
    puts("Good");
}
```

Comment: why that random `%7s`? just use `" %c"` which should be sufficient

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I agree, that would have worked. I was originally going to use another `%d` but put in a better catch.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your code.

```c
int input[8] = {0};                     // (1)
int countM = 0;
while(countM < 9){
    if(scanf("%d", &input[countM]) < 8) // (2)
    ...
}
```

In (1), you define an array of length 8. In (2), you have a while loop that goes through 9 integers (from 0 to 8). During the final run of the loop, you have the equivalent of

```c
scanf("%d", &input[8] < 8)
```

which goes out of bounds of the array. Out of bounds, there be dragons. Further, the `< 8` comparison doesn't do what you want it to do.

If you intend to check the bounds, you should do so **before** you access or assign that part of the array.

For example:

```c
while(countM < 9){
    if (countM > 7)
    {
        // do whatever you want when this should happen
        break;
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

But as you can see, this is a bit weird. You know you'll trigger that code.

You can do better with something like

```c
int val;
int countM = 0;
while (scanf("%d", &val) == 1)
{
    if (countM > 7)
    {
        printf("Whoops");
        // whatever you want
        exit(1);
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: @chux Of course, you're right. I'll edit my answer.